# rotatelogs %F and common

Tags: apache

seeing

```
 logs/access.%F
```

in the what is the %F mean? did not see it in the docs

Additionally in the docs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html seems like there is a keyword of 'common' yet no explanation what does the word common do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"common" is the name of a `LogFormat` that's present in the default configuration.  Here's the definition from the mod_log_config manual:

> "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"

But in this case, %F is not part of a `LogFormat` but passed by rotatelogs to your systems strftime() function as part of a filename.

If %F actually means something on your system (it doesn't on mine) you can check `man 3 strftime` and look for it.

Answer (score 0):

`%F` may be from the module [mod_log_firstbyte](https://github.com/letynsoft/mod-log-firstbyte) and is "the time spent processing the request excluding the time required for receiving and sending data." Sometimes this is called "time to first byte".

Search your configs for a line like "loadModule log_firstbyte_module"